# How to split a data that comes from select element using jQuery and Ajax

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax

My problem is when splitting a data. What I did was I created a 3 `<select>` elements. I manage and successfully got the data and tried splitting it. First select element is to choose a person, upon clicking it, it will display another data inside second element and then upon select the result will append it's corresponding data to the third select element. Problem I could not separate it and when I tried splitting it doesn't work.

Here is the images

[image]

The encircled ones means that they are the separated option inside my ajax and it's variable name is `'<option value="'.$row['section_model'].'">'. $row['section_model'] .'</option>'` and my goal is to append it to my third select element. Then the un-circled ones means it should stay inside selection labeled Department.

The second picture is where I hope someone can help me how will I split and then append the encircled datas from my first picture and put inside my third selection element.

[image]

Here is my code

```js
function ToolsChange(element) {
  let tools_controller = $(element).val();
  if (tools_controller) {

    $.ajax({
      type: "post",
      url: "form_ajax_for_request.php",
      data: {
        "tools_cont": tools_controller
      },
      success: function(response) {
        // alert(response);
        var dataSplit = response;
        var shouldSplit = dataSplit.split("@");
        // alert(shouldSplit[1]);
        $('#sel_requested_dept').html('');
        $('#sel_requested_dept').append(response);
        $('#sel_requested_dept').selectpicker('refresh');

        $('#sel_requested_section').html('');
        $('#sel_requested_section').append(shouldSplit[2]);
        $('#sel_requested_section').selectpicker('refresh');
      }
    });

  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
  <label> Tools Controller: </label>
  <select class="form-control selectpicker" name="tools_controller" data-live-search="true" onchange="ToolsChange(this)" required>
    <option value="" selected disabled> Select Tools Controller </option>
    <?php
      $query = "SELECT * FROM tools_dept_registration";
      $con->next_result();
      $result=mysqli_query($con,$query);
      if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0)
      {
         while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
         {
          echo '<option value="'.$row['name_of_controller'].'">'. $row['name_of_controller'] 
          .'</option>';
         }
      }                                               
   ?>
  </select>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <label> Department </label>
  <select name="request_dept" id="sel_requested_dept" class="form-control selectpicker" data-live- 
    search="true" required>
    <option value="" selected disabled> Select Department </option>

  </select>
</div>


<div class="form-group">
  <label> Section/Model </label>
  <select name="request_section_model" id="sel_requested_section" class="form-control selectpicker" data-live-search="true" required>
    <option value="" selected disabled> Select Section/Model </option>

  </select>
</div>
```

Whole code inside my ajax/php

```
<?php 

include("../include/connect.php");

 
    if(isset($_POST['tools_cont'])){

        $ID = $_POST['tools_cont'];

        $query = "SELECT * FROM tools_dept_registration 
        RIGHT JOIN tools_section_model_reg ON tools_section_model_reg.dept_id = tools_dept_registration.ID
        WHERE name_of_controller = '$ID'";
        $con->next_result();
        $result=mysqli_query($con, $query);
        
        if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0)
        {
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
            {
                echo "@" . '<option value="'.$row['dept_name'].'">'. $row['dept_name'] . " - " . $row['ass_leader'] . '</option>' 
                . "@" .'<option value="'.$row['section_model'].'">'. $row['section_model'] .'</option>';
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `for-loop` to iterate through splitting values and check if the value of `i` is even depending on this add your option to required select-boxes.

***Demo Code*** :

```js
function ToolsChange(element) {
  let tools_controller = $(element).val();
  if (tools_controller) {

    /*$.ajax({
      //your other,,code..
      success: function(response) {*/
    //suppose reponse look like this
    var response = '@<option value=C>C - D</option>@<option value=S>Sm</option>@<option value=D>D - E</option>@<option value=S1>Sm1</option>@<option value=M>D - M</option>@<option value=S2>Sm2</option>'
    var dataSplit = response;
    $('#sel_requested_dept').html('');
    $('#sel_requested_section').html('');
    var shouldSplit = dataSplit.split("@");
    for (var i = 0; i < shouldSplit.length; i++) {
      //check if at even position 
      if (i % 2 == 0) {
        $('#sel_requested_section').append(shouldSplit[i]);
      } else {
        $('#sel_requested_dept').append(shouldSplit[i]);
      }

    }
    $('#sel_requested_dept').selectpicker('refresh');
    $('#sel_requested_section').selectpicker('refresh');
    /*}
    });*/

  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.12.3/css/bootstrap-select.min.css">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.12.3/js/bootstrap-select.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
  <label> Tools Controller: </label>
  <select class="form-control selectpicker" name="tools_controller" data-live-search="true" onchange="ToolsChange(this)" required>
    <option value="" selected disabled> Select Tools Controller </option>
    <option value="A"> A </option>
    <option value="B"> B </option>
  </select>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <label> Department </label>
  <select name="request_dept" id="sel_requested_dept" class="form-control selectpicker" data-live- search="true" required>
    <option value="" selected disabled> Select Department </option>

  </select>
</div>


<div class="form-group">
  <label> Section/Model </label>
  <select name="request_section_model" id="sel_requested_section" class="form-control selectpicker" data-live-search="true" required>
    <option value="" selected disabled> Select Section/Model </option>

  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi! :) . I have a question, I understood the part where it needs to loop but what is the meaning in this syntax `if (i % 2 == 0) {  $('#sel_requested_section').append(shouldSplit[i]);} else {$('#sel_requested_dept').append(shouldSplit[i]);}` . Sorry I did not understood this part hehe. Seems complicated to me hehe. Thank you very much for the answer :)))

Comment: When you will split response it will be array of values starting from index `0,1..etc` so php code is returning options separated by `@` so at position  `0` will be first option ,at position `1` there will have second option and so on . So , according to your code options which are at even position belongs to third dropdown  to access same we have use `shouldSplit[i]` where `i` is divisible by `2`  and for second dropdown we need odd position options so `i` will be odd nos .

Comment: Ohhhhhh now I get it, I tried to console.log and saw it was in even numbers. But what if I input another set of data will there be any disruptions or disturbance on what you said here `array of values starting from index 0,1..etc so php code is returning options separated by @ so at position 0 will be first option ,at position 1 there will have second option and so on` ? or will run fine despite if how many data will be entered and fetched from server.

Comment: according to this code there are options for two different selects so no matter how many options you have it will work fine. Also, i suggest you using `json` here to return options from php .

Comment: it would be more easier to handle  datas you just need some loop to iterate through your values . There are many tutorial to do same (i,e return json data from php to ajax)

Comment: Ohhhhh wow! Okay will study it later. Thank you for helping, I learned a lot :))

Comment: Hi @Swati I have a question again if it is okay? :) , I have to change something in my code and confused me a little bit due to the for loop and on how will I make the output dependent on `<select>` element by clicking it, is it okay to proceed to chat discussion or shall I post another question?

Comment: I  think you should ask anothe question :) Because above issue is already solved so .

Comment: Hi @Swati here is my link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66344759/how-can-i-append-values-through-and-will-depend-on-the-data-from-select-elem :) thanks