# How can I append values through and will depend on the data from `<select>` element?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax

What I have tried is to use $.each to get the index and the value but I don't know how or what will I do next. I have an ajax, output is I have 3 elements where I get my data and split it to put it into other 2 elements which is a `<select>` and an `<input>` element. My goal is when I will select a data from my second `<select>` element, it's corresponding data will append to the `<input>` value or in short the data that will be filled up automatically inside my `<input>` element will be dependent on the data that was clicked on my `<select>` element.

Here is the image of what I got from the console when I split my data

[image]

Here is what I got when I did the $.each()

[image]

What my goal is each of the names linked to even numbers in my console should be inside my input element labeled "Leader" depending to it's section model which is above them (names)

Here is my whole code

```js
function ToolsChange(element) {

  let tools_controller = $(element).val();

  // alert(tools_controller);

  if (tools_controller) {

    $.ajax({
      type: "post",
      url: "form_ajax_for_request.php",
      data: {
        "tools_cont": tools_controller
      },
      success: function(response) {
        // alert(response);
        // console.log(response);
        var dataSplit = response;
        var shouldSplit = dataSplit.split("@");
        // alert(shouldSplit);
        console.log(shouldSplit);

        $('#sel_requested_section').html('');
        $('#sel_requested_section').append(response);
        $('#sel_requested_section').selectpicker('refresh');
        // $('#request_leader').val(shouldSplit[10]);
        $.each(shouldSplit, function(index, value) {
          console.log(index);
          console.log(value);
        });
      }
    });
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="form-group">
  <label> Department: </label>
  <select class="form-control selectpicker" name="tools_controller" data-live-search="true" onchange="ToolsChange(this)" required>
    <option value="" selected disabled> Select Department </option>
    <?php
     $query = "SELECT * FROM tools_dept_registration";
     $con->next_result();
     $result=mysqli_query($con,$query);
       if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0)
       {
          while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
          {
            echo '<option value="'. $row['dept_name'] .'">'.$row['dept_name'] . " - " . $row['name_of_controller'] .'</option>';
          }
        }                                               
     ?>
  </select>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <label> Section/Model </label>
  <select name="request_dept" id="sel_requested_section" class="form-control selectpicker" data-live-search="true" required>
    <option value="" selected disabled> Select Section/Model </option>

  </select>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <label> Leader </label>
  <input class="form-control" id="request_leader" name="request_leader" readonly>
</div>
```

Here is my ajax/PHP

```
<?php 

include("../include/connect.php");

 
    if(isset($_POST['tools_cont'])){

        $ID = $_POST['tools_cont'];

        $query = "SELECT * FROM tools_dept_registration 
        LEFT JOIN tools_section_model_reg ON tools_section_model_reg.dept_id = 
        tools_dept_registration.ID WHERE dept_name = '$ID'";
        $con->next_result();
        $result=mysqli_query($con, $query);
        
        if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0)
        {
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
            {
                echo "@". '<option value="'.$row['section_model'].'">'. $row['section_model'] 
                .'</option>' . "@" . $row['ass_leader'];
               
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: HI there is only one input box `request_leader` ? where that all name should come then ?

Comment: Yes one input box :) . All name came from the second `<select>` element labeled Section/Model. That is why it is not appending because I already split it inside my jQuery. Sorry that made you confused.

Comment: you can add that name inside your option as an data-attribute i.e : `echo  '<option value="'.$row['section_model'].'" data-leader="'.$row['ass_leader'].'">'. $row['section_model']  .'</option>'` (sorry for syntax error i have not tested) and then when your select gets change get that data-leader value and show in your input .Also , remove this `. "@" . $row['ass_leader']` whole part .

Comment: Okay I did what exactly you are telling me. Problem is I think I need to get each index? I am not so sure if it should be like that or for loop?

Comment: no then just append that option inside your select-box no need to use each loop .. i.e :  `$('#sel_requested_section').html(''); $('#sel_requested_section').append(response); $('#sel_requested_section').selectpicker('refresh');` only this three line needed remove all other codes from success function .Also make sure `console.log(response);` showing you all option correctly

Comment: It did not work haha. I am so confused sorry

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229134/discussion-between-swati-and-error-401).